# Help Identifying Molex plug

Tags: power-supply, plug

I'm looking for some help identifying which plug to get for this power source. I know the specs of the original power source are "120V, 60Hz AC linear power supply; output is 6 volts DC, 2 amps." I'm having a hard time finding the correct plug for this application, though. The original supplier is backordered until late August/early September. Here is a picture of what is on the board:

[image]

Comment: What is the pin to pin spacing?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify dimensions, but it seems like a plain old Mini-Fit Jr connector, with two positions.

If you could measure the part, you should hopefully find it to be 4.2mm pitch (pin to pin distance), and 9.6 x 5.4mm Outer dimensions (excluding flanges). Scaling off the mini-USB connector, this seems to be about right.

Specifically part number [874270242](https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/part-detail/874270242), which as can be seen from the image below appears to be the same connector right down to the various flanges and ribs.

[image: Photo of connector showing same ribs and flanges]

<sup>[Image Sourced from Manufacturer Webpage](https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/part-detail/874270242)</sup>

Comment: This looks to be exactly it! I measured it with my calipers and those are the correct measurements. Thank you so much, you're awesome!